# Strange Database table must end on a s

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am working with vs2010 entity framework 4.1 I installed some from the nuget installers
I use codefirst on an existing database. (dutch database)
If I use in my models  derived from :DbContext

```
public DbSet<Klant> Klant { get; set; }
```

> The error : Invalid object name
>   'dbo.Klants'

I don't have a table "klants" but "klant"
If I change the table name that ends on a "s" no problem, but I can't change this. It's is used by other programs as well.

Does someone else has this problem??

What can I do???:?

Cheers

Comment: I think this is caused by the Entity Framework, which tries to pluralize the entities (tables). I'm not sure though! Take a look at the Entity Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your `.edmx` does not have `Pluralize names` set to `true` in its properties.

I got headaches with it too.

Answer (score 1):

It's a configurable option: [Entity Framework 4.0: Pluralization](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/19/entity-framework-40-pluralization/)

[image]

Comment: Watch out: I don't know if it's my Visual Studio 2010 or what, but even if I remove the flag when modifying the data model through the wizard (i.e. adding entities from the database), the property will still be `true` and the next time will be checked again. I have to edit the `.edmx` property to make it persistent. I screwed up many times because of this "feature"...

Comment: Thanks!! that helps but......the pluralisation is to false. But still it asks for plural. Each Table in the model is also NOT set to plural. What else to do, to get rid of this feature(?)

Comment: Hi Guys, [I found this sollution](http://cookiesforgeeks.blogspot.com/2011/04/plural-table-name-error-with-entity.html)